# Play Audio when GameObjects are no longer active?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an empty game object that plays audios specifically when certain tagged game objects are no longer visible. When the function `FindObjects` were in the function `Update()` it repetitively played the audio over and over when the objects were visible. Now I'm unsure why or how to have this function play out.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DeathSound : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource owl;
    public AudioSource enemy;
    public AudioSource enemy2;

    void Start () {
        owl = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void FindObjects () {
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag ("Owl") != null)
        {
            owl.Play ();
        }
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag ("Enemy") != null) 
        {
            enemy2.Play ();
            enemy.Play ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is not null, it will play the audio. If you want if it is null then play audio, you should change that to == not !=

Comment: Alsa have you checked [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1069818/how-do-i-get-my-audio-to-play-once.html) before?

Comment: What's the intended functionality? How could we help you if we don't know something as simple as that?

Comment: @TJWolschon Its in the description.

Comment: No, actually it's not. You've given us the functionality that you don't want.

Comment: @Thalthanas I tried == but it played constantly so I'm guessing its because that was in update. I will try == once more!

Comment: @TJWolschon I have no idea why I find you in all of my questions but proceed to be.

Comment: I like to help people, I don't intend to have my comments come across as mean. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding what you've written? Can you try rewriting your description? Also, try using the suggested methods in the answer by KYL3R, you might find them useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is [OnBecameInvisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) and also [OnDisable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html)

these may help you playing a sound when the units die.